# Inno Setup invoke or replicate native Windows file copy operation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I know that the `FileCopy` function can be used to copy files in the `[Code]` section and this works fine for most purposes. However, is there any way to invoke the native Windows file copy operation, so that the standard Windows file copy dialog with progress, time remaining etc is shown (i.e. the same as doing `Ctrl+C`, followed by `Ctrl+V`), which will also allow the user to cancel or pause the copy operation mid-process? Or, better still, is there a way to replicate similar functionality directly in the `[Code]` section?

Comment: The Windows SHFileOperation() API (Or less easily IFileOperation) is what you would have to invoke in code to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) with `FO_COPY`:

```pascal
type
  TSHFileOpStruct = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    wFunc: UINT;
    pFrom: string;
    pTo: string;
    fFlags: Word;
    fAnyOperationsAborted: BOOL; 
    hNameMappings: HWND;
    lpszProgressTitle: string;
  end; 

const
  FO_COPY            = $0002;
  FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = $0010;

function SHFileOperation(lpFileOp: TSHFileOpStruct): Integer;
  external 'SHFileOperationW@shell32.dll stdcall';

procedure ShellCopyFile;
var
  FromPath: string;
  ToPath: string;
  FileOp: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  FromPath :=
    ExpandConstant('{src}\data1.dat') + #0 +
    ExpandConstant('{src}\data2.dat') + #0;
  ToPath := ExpandConstant('{app}') + #0;

  FileOp.hwnd := WizardForm.Handle;
  FileOp.wFunc := FO_COPY;
  FileOp.pFrom := FromPath;
  FileOp.pTo := ToPath;
  FileOp.fFlags := FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;

  if SHFileOperation(FileOp) <> 0 then
  begin
    MsgBox('Copying failed.', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;  
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    ShellCopyFile;
  end;
end;
```

*The code is for Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin. This looks pretty much perfect. Is possible to pass it multiple files to copy? It looks like this is limited to one file at a time?

Comment: Sure, it is possible. See documentation for [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795.aspx) and my edited answer. Actually I had a bug in the previous code. You can either use file list or wildcard to specify multiple files for the operation.