# Defining structure with wide character pointer field in Inno Setup Unicode

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Some external libraries, notably Windows API, use structure types with some fields being a pointer to a character array.

Inno Setup Unicode does not have `PChar` (`PWideChar`) type. How do I define a structure, that uses fields of wide character array pointer type?

For example how do I define [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shfileopstructw)?

```pascal
type
  TSHFileOpStruct = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    wFunc: UINT;
    pFrom: { what type? }
    pTo: { what type? }
    fFlags: Word;
    fAnyOperationsAborted: BOOL; 
    hNameMappings: HWND;
    lpszProgressTitle: { what type? }
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string` type. In Inno Setup Unicode Pascal Script the `string` type is automatically marshaled to `PWideChar`-like type in some contexts:

- In `record` definitions (what the question is about).
- In argument and return-type declarations of [`external` functions](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll).

So the definition of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure is:

```pascal
type
  TSHFileOpStruct = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    wFunc: UINT;
    pFrom: string;
    pTo: string;
    fFlags: Word;
    fAnyOperationsAborted: BOOL; 
    hNameMappings: HWND;
    lpszProgressTitle: string;
  end;
```

For a use, see [Inno Setup invoke or replicate native Windows file copy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45244210/850848).

In all (?) other contexts, the `string` keeps its unique intrinsic function from Pascal language.